# Create a windows service to kill a program logged into from web browser like IE 11, that has been idle or not used after 30 minutes

Tags: c#

I want to create a background windows service that if a user is idle or not using say like after 30 minutes, to go ahead and stop or kill their program on a web browser.
Is this possible with Visual Studio 2017, C#?
You see, we have limited licenses available and do not want to stop or kill them all but only selected ones that have been 'idle' or not used after 30 minutes.
Thanks,
MG

Nothing tried yet, just a new idea so far.
Need to figure out what syntax to use and what would be the best approach in knowing when a program the user has been logged into hasn't been used or sitting idle.  This would be within IE or other web browsers.

pseudo-code:
create windows service
if the program the user is logged into is idle after 30 minutes then
     kill their program on their web browser
end if;

This windows service will be installed on all local machines and ran in the background.
If after 30 minutes of idle, then this window service should kill their program.

Comment: Killing a program is fairly easy, even if I doubt it will be more difficult with a Windows service. (the service must run with a machine's administrator user).

If it's a particular program that you have access the source code, I recommand to add an idle detection mode, and If the user do not play with your program, gently close the software.

If you don't have access to the source code of your program, you real problem is to detect the lack of activity: How can your user interact with the software?

Comment: I'm not understanding how the web browser relates to any of this.  Is the application being killed to free up a license running inside a web browser?  Is a web page being used to confirm whether the application should be killed or keep running?  Can you write out step-by-step a typical hour in the life of your proposed system?

Comment: Thanks for the Comments.  I'm going to give a funny example.

Comment: Thanks for the Comments.  I'm going to give a funny example.  Supposed that I have a paid dating site with 10 licenses.  The user would access the site using a username / password.  This would constitute 1 license.  So if a user tries to access the site, it will not let him, if these all 10 licenses are used.  Users are guilty for not signing out if they are not using the site, looking for their Mr. or Ms Right.  Like they are away from their desk, computer or laptop.

Comment: Without access to source code or admin rights, I'd like to create a windows service that checks to see if a logged-in user has not have any activity for a period length of time.  I do have access to the actual database - Oracle where maybe that can be used to check for a specified idle time.